# CQRS and DDD: File uploads

Tags: api, file-upload, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I'm new to the concept of DDD and CQRS and can't find a final solution how to upload images, or files in general, in a clean way.

Imagine the following scenario:
In an online portal there is a support request formular where a file (image in specific) could be attached to.
The posted data will raise a `CreateSupportRequestCommand`. Then the required aggregates will be loaded and changed.

I have three ideas to solve this, but I'm not very satisfied with them.

**Way 1:**
1. Post all data including the image (multipart) in a single request
2. Create a `FileUploadCommand`, which is returning the `FileUploadId`.
3. After that create a `CreateSupportRequestCommand` and pass the `FileUploadId` with the root data in the constructor.
Drawback: A single request will trigger two commands. In terms of CQRS one user interaction should be only one command.

**Way 2:**
1. Post the image to a seperate endpoint, create a temporary file and return the id or a file handle.
2. Post the formular with the attached tempfile id.
3. Invoke the `CreateSupportRequestCommand` with all root data including a file handle which points to the physical file.
4. Inside the command persist the tempfile into a `FileUpload` aggregate (by `FileUploadRepository`) then
5. Create the `SupportRequest` aggregate, assign the FileUploadId and persist.
Drawback: I handle 2 aggregates in the same command. Creating a support request is not responsible for uploading the file.

**Way 3:**
1. Post the image to a seperate endpoint, create a temporary file and return the id or a file handle.
2. Post the formular with the attached tempfile id.
3. Invoke the `CreateSupportRequestCommand` with all root data including a file handle which points to the physical file.
4. Only persist the root data to the `SupportRequest` aggregate. Raise a `SupportRequestCreatedEvent` and attach the file handle.
5. Inside the event process and assign the file handle.
Drawback: The `SupportRequestCreatedEvent` should not really care about a file handle.

Is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not think handling File upload is a Domain Concern. The file metadata like `FileContentId` may be part of your domain but not the actual file upload. I would perform the file operation before the `CommandHandler` is executed. Probably in a middleware or perhaps before queing up the `Command` onto the message bus.

`CreateSupportRequestCommandHandler` would then only be invoking an `operation` like `CreateSupportRequest` on your aggrerate (say `SupportRequest`). Within that `CreateSupportRequest` method you will have all your business rule pretaining to the operation. `SupportRequest` then eventually would be saved in your repository.